# Htaccess case sensitive rewrite condition issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have written a rewrite rule for my website as below;

```
 RewriteEngine on
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
 RewriteRule ^([^.php].+) /details.php?name=$0
```

When I am trying www.example.com/example and it will be redirected to www.example.com/details.php?name=example.
But I have tried to access the same like www.example.com/Example but it fails.

Please let me know how can get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ,

```
CheckSpelling on
```

Summary

*CheckSpelling is a nice way towards a more “tolerant” website experience and to unburden error logs since it can be used to auto-correct file requests. When activated, this “spell checker” compares each document name in the requested directory against the requested document name without regard to case, and it allows up to one misspelling (character insertion, omission, transposition, or a wrong character).*

**Example for CheckSpelling being enabled**: `CheckSpelling On.`

[Reference Liink](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20070412/htaccess-7-useful-ingredients-plus-bonus/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem appears to be in your rule that is using an incorrect regex.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /details.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```